# How can I add a sub array to an array?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build an array to create a menu system where each index has 2 objects, a name and a subarray of Strings.

I tried something like this:

```
var menus = [];
menus.push({title:"Aztec", mySubArray:{"String1", "String2","String3"} });
```

but that doesnt seem to be the right syntax. any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 5):

You have a syntax error, `mySubArray` has to be an array `[]`

```
var menus = [];
menus.push({title:"Aztec", mySubArray:["String1", "String2","String3"] });
```

Comment: Ah, for some reason I thought that wouldn't work and skipped it over. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`mySubArray` is not a valid object, because it's missing property names, which makes it an array. You can fix this by either making `mySubArray` an array:

```
mySubArray:["String1", "String2","String3"]
```

or by adding property names to make it an actual object:

```
mySubArray:{1: "String1", 2: "String2",3: "String3"}
```

The issue isn't with the fact that it's a "sub array" being pushed, only with the syntax of the actual `mySubArray` value.